# In TCP/IP Model why transport layer functionality referred to Host to Host but not process to process?

Tags: networking

In my understanding, the transport layer begins to use the port numbers which is the identifier for a process. However the transport layer still referred as host to host functionality. What is the reason in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) I don't think transport layer is commonly referred to as host to host, it is referred to as end-to-end, as in, it works on both endpoints, and not in the network itself. This was intended in original design. Of course now there are a lot of network devices that look into transport layer. However, main functionality is still on hosts.

(2) although transport layer begins to use ports to segregate applications/processes, transport layer is the one doing the segregation. One of its functionality is to take packets from the IP layer and attribute them to the correct application. In this sense, there is only one instance of transport layer per host. Several processes are using that single transport layer. (We could argue about whether tcp and udp processing are separate entities, but this is implementation detail. But all tcp packets, which can be processed on each core, have to be attributed to correct sockets, so there is one instance of tcp per host)

(3)  ports do not identify processes, ports identify sockets. each process can open more than one socket. reverse is not true, a socket is attributed to a single process.

Comment: 2nd point has the sense

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of the Host-to-Host Layer or Transport Layer is to shield the upper layers from the process of sending data. Also provides an end-to-end connection between two devices during communication by performing sequencing, acknowledgments, checksums, and flow control. Applications using services at this layer can use two different protocols: TCP and UDP.

Protocols at the Host-to-Host Layer are:

TCP (Transmission Control Protocol)
TCP provides a connection-oriented, reliable services to the applications that use its services.

Comment: My doubt is why it is called Host to Host layer?

Comment: "_Applications using services at this layer can use two different protocols: TCP and UDP._" Actually, there are many more transport protocols that can be used, e.g. SCTP, DCCP, etc. See the _[IANA Protocol Numbers](https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml)_ page for the various transport protocols.